# Get session attribute having attribute name in a constants file

Tags: session, jsf-2, el

I want to get a session attribute from xhtml file. I know that if you put the attribute name like this `#{sessionAttributeName.field}` it works but my problem comes when I try to get the attribute name from a constants file.

I've imported the constants file with `<p:importConstants type="Constants" var="constants"/>`

I've tried get the attribute using `#{constants.constantAttributeName.field}` (***constantAttributeName*** value is ***sessionAttributeName***) but, how I expected, it doesn't work.

Is it possible get the session attribute using the constant with another method or another way to do this?

I could put directly the attribute name in all xhtml files, but if it changes, I should change all files.

Do you have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I've used `#{sessionScope[constants.constantAttributeName].field}` and now it's working.

Comment: What you effectively use here is EL, Expression Language, not specifically related to JSF